# How to redirect output from an executable to a batch file's caller?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a batch file, how can I start an executable and redirect the output, as if the caller of the batch file started the executable itself?

```
process.exe > batch.bat > commandline.exe
---------------------------------< Output
```

Comment: Give an example of what the task is.  If the process.exe runs, then the batch file and creates a text file of the output - will the process.exe then use the text file?  Show the command line for process.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on input/output streams and how to redirect them. An excellent article about that: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php

In your case, `@ECHO OFF` at the start of your batch file will probably do the trick. If you include that, only explicit outputs (such as those from `commandline.exe` in your example) will "bubble up" and reach the caller.